# Calling base class' constructor without defining it in derived class

Tags: c++

```
class A {
public:
  int _a
  A(int a) : _a { a} { }
};

class B : public A { }
```

Why can't I initialize a variable of A type with using the inherited constructor?

```
B a(5);
```

Error: "No matching constructor for initialization of 'B'"

Comment: Remember to specify a virtual desctructor or a protected non-virtual one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `B` doesn't have such a constructor taking `int` by default, unless [inherit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) it explicitly:

```
class B : public A { 
    using A::A; // inheriting constructor
};
```

Comment: is there a way to make this implicit, so that any subclasses of a class will always inherit the base class' constructor without using the `using` directive?

Comment: @luis AFAIK, no.